# Sort Matched Files by Last Modified and Timestamp

Tags: unix

I need to look for files that match a certain pattern of characters, then find the most recent file and display it. The below code isn't quite getting me there but, I think I'm close.

**Code:**

```
find /home/weather/data/blend/ -type f -name "*.ctl" -printf '%Ts\t%p\n' | sort -nr | cut -f2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working solution:

```
find . -mmin -720 -type f -name "*.ctl" -exec ls -t {} \; | cut -c 3-
```